# Styling add to calendar

Tags: css

I'd love to have this design in my email for add to calendar. I have the links for each calendar already, but in case any of you know how to style it to be like this? Would be great

Thanks in advance
[style like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xY5pp.jpg)

Comment: Provide the links in order to get the icons.

Comment: Hei, thanks, I checked a few forums yesterday, and it seems that ExactTarget mail can't load the icons, so I guess, if I want to use the icons, I have to do it as images...